# Flutter_blue error when permission denied

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth

I use package Flutter_blue, it asks permission for bluetooth at start and crashes app when permission denied. How can I stop app from crashing? I want it to work even when user denies bluetooth access and for example show screen saying 'give access to bluetooth'

Answer (score 0):

It should actually not ask for permission referring the following from the permission_handler package, according to them:

> Some permissions will not show a dialog asking the user to allow or deny the requested permission.
> This is because the OS setting(s) of the app are being retrieved for the corresponding permission.
> The status of the setting will determine whether the permission is `granted` or `denied`.

> The following permissions will show no dialog:
> **Notification**, **Bluetooth**

Well, you can do ask for permission if not granted on iOS though with `permission_handler`, for more information checkout the [`permission_handler`](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) package (more specifically [`Bluetooth`](https://pub.dev/documentation/permission_handler_platform_interface/latest/permission_handler_platform_interface/Permission/bluetooth-constant.html) constant)

Just make sure to add those permissions in the AndroidManifest & Info.plist specified in the [`flutter_blue`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue) package docs.

Just a little disclaimer, for the concept regarding requesting permission on android, I might be wrong. Please correct me if wrong.